# How to use Javascript/jQuery to load the content from another domain?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to create a javascript application that can display the content from another domain (admittedly another big website). Further interpretation of the DOM tree is not needed at the moment. It will be used by only ten more people.

I can make it work via php's get_content function. But that is very slow since it runs on the server side. I looked into any origin but cannot get it to work. It is best to not touch any origin since we use it extensively and we don't have much cash to spend around. Can anyone help? By the way, iframe is not an option since the big website blocked it. The code is below. Admittedly I kind of took it from another stackoverflow answer. Thank you in advance!

Btw. another engineer told me if I use the extension .hta instead of html, the same-origin policy issue would be resolved. I tried it and it did not work. But I was wondering if I did it right.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myCallbackFunction(myData) {
    $(function() {
        $("#test").contents().find('html').html(myData.contents);
    });
}
</script>
<script src="http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001F7SGHQ/&callback=myCallbackFunction"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<iframe id='test' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php)? You will surely see the performance difference against `*_get_content` function.

Comment: @RahilWazir I have not tried it but the other engineer doesn't like I am using server-side since the server has been way too crowdy now.

Comment: You have no choice but to do it server-side; the same-origin policy prevents you from loading it via JavaScript. Just implement some sort of caching, and your server load will go way down.

Comment: @EdCottrell The issue is that we worry frequenting one website (i.e. amazon) too much will arise problems. Apparently the other engineer had this problem before when we do too much crawling.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following.

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001F7SGHQ/&callback=myCallbackFunction';

function callOtherDomain() {
  if(invocation) {
    invocation.open('GET', url, true);
    invocation.withCredentials = true;
    invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
    invocation.send(); 
  }
}
```

Addition of [withCredentials = true] will enable the HTTP header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:".

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you give a html included code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there's another good solution might be what you need via PHP ,
is to use class called PHP

> Simple HTML DOM Parser

this class can copy all source of a websites and you can save it in your server with extension you want also you can modified what you need before you save and this class have a full documentation (You need to be good in PHP5 POO )
this a link for class

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

and there a good advanced thing you can do it for make your website faster , is use a Cash System so you can download the source from website one time a Day or 1H or 12 Hours ,
and save it in your host .
i hope that will give you what you need .